# how to make blank rows skipped by using laravel excel (import)

Tags: excel, laravel, import

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'branch' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `data_collection` (`branch`, `deal_type`, `deal_ref`, `cif`, `suffix`, `short_name`, `ccy`, `cot_date`, `start_date`, `mat_date`, `commitement`, `col_ucs`, `dpd`, `col`, `plafond`, `os`, `pastdue_interest`, `pastdue_principal`, `int_rate`, `int_accrued`, `bunga`, `gol`, `hub`, `sf`, `jp`, `op`, `gk`, `sk`, `lok`, `penjamin`, `kode_dinas`, `kode_asuransi`, `alamat`, `no_telp`, `tgl_lahir`, `aoro`, `usia`, `sms`, `wa`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 1970-01-01 00:00:00, 1970-01-01 00:00:00, 1970-01-01 00:00:00, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 1970-01-01 00:00:00, ?, ?, ?, ?, 2020-02-05 06:53:18, 2020-02-05 06:53:18))

Comment: in your database change `branch` dafault value as NULL

Comment: Can you show your code? It will help us a lot in helping you.